# Springer journal math font

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to troubleshoot proofs for an article in a Springer (linguistics) journal. It'd be useful to test out some potential solutions myself rather than describing what I want to the typesetters and asking them to figure things out.

However, I can't figure out how to approximate the Springer math font. It looks similar in some respects (e.g., delimiters) to newtxmath, but other things look unlike any package I'm familiar with (e.g., the Greek letters, `mathsf`/`mathtt`).

Is there any way to approximate Springer's latex style (in particular, the math font), or is this impossible without whatever proprietary tools they're using?

Editing to add a photo of a representative formula. The delimiters and the alphabetic letters are very `newtxmath`, the `\lambda` and binary/relational operations are not. 
[image]

Comment: Springer, several years ago, had a ‘Springer font’, based on Adobe's `Minion Pro`. Maybe  try to see if the  homonymous package yields a correct result.

Comment: See the update. Doesn't look Minion-y.

Comment: I think they use the [MathTime Professional 2](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) fonts, a subset of which (the so-called Lite version) can be downloaded, installed and used for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accepting totally the considerations of the comment of @Pavel Rudnev, you can choose one of these two code.

In addition to the standard symbol `\lambda` with the package `mtpro2` (version not complete called `[lite]`), there is also the symbol `\uplambda`.

[image]
**First code**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[\uplambda, \rightarrow\]
\end{document}
```

Using the package `newtxmath` with the option `[libertine]` you can obtain a similar symbol as this image below:

[image]
                   **Second code**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[\uplambda\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree it's based on `mtpro2` with some borrowings from `newtxmath` and perhaps elsewhere. (Interesting, the `\uplambda` is vertically squished in the proofs for some reason or other.) The `\rightarrow` is the giveaway.

Comment: Thank you for to have accepted my answer. However the answer is given bt @Pavel Rudnev :-). For libertine I have taken severals hours to find it.